# Can't get SharePoint access token

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, oauth, sharepoint-2013

I have created an app in SharePoint 2013, using **AppRegNew.aspx**, from where I got an app secrete and id. For this app I set permissions of reading and writing to Documents list, using **AppInv.aspx**.

Now, I want to use the app secrete and Id from another project to access the documents list. I am using TokenHelper class like below:

```
TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken
```

But I get an exception:

> *The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. - The requested namespace does not exist.*

I debugged the code from TokeHelper class and found that the exception comes from this web call:

https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/metadata/json/1?realm=my_realm_value

which is located in method:

```
private static JsonMetadataDocument GetMetadataDocument(string realm)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to figure it out. I used a SharePoint app that had the following permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Write">
    <Property Name="BaseTemplateId" Value="101"/>
  </AppPermissionRequest>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Beside this I used a certificate in order to get the access token. That certificate I linked with the app and set it as a trust token issuer using a PowerShell script:

```
$issuerID = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToLower()
$publicCertPath = "your_cer_file.cer"
$certificate = Get-PfxCertificate $publicCertPath
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://your.sharepoint.url/"
$realm = Get-SPAuthenticationRealm -ServiceContext $web.Site
$fullAppIdentifier = $issuerId + '@' + $realm
New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer -Name "High Trust App" -Certificate $certificate - RegisteredIssuerName $fullAppIdentifier -IsTrustBroker
$issuerID
iisreset
```

Then I used TokenHelper class like this:

```
var siteUri = new Uri("my_site_url");
TokenHelper.GetS2SAccessTokenWithWindowsIdentity(siteUri, null);
```

Comment: though you got it working these  are 2 different ways of getting token

Comment: though you got it working these  are 2 different ways of getting token. the option where u got error is the Low Trust Oauth token, which failed because the GetMetadataDocument(string realm) internally uses webclient to talk to ACS and if your working in a proxy environment, you need to set the proxy explicitly like webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxy.com"); . The option 2 which you got working is by making it a high trust app by using certificates and without Oauth